# Autocompletion for GtkAda in GNAT GPS

Tags: autocomplete, ada, gnat, gnat-gps

I'm just getting started with Ada and GtkAda development using GNAT GPS (Gnat Programming Studio), and there is something that is frustrating me: autocompletion (ie: intellisense, or whatever you want to call it) only works for my code, but not for the GtkAda library.
This makes things quite slow and boring, since I have to check every API call on the GtkAda documentation every time.

So my question is simple: is there a way to enable auto completion for GtkAda on GPS?

Comment: I just tried and it works for me. Do you have a GPR file for your project which calls up GtkAda's GPR? I'm using GPS 2013 GPL on Mac OS X (ML).

Comment: I'm still on GNAT 2012... I'll update now, see if it fixes it.

Comment: Yep that was it, works in GNAT GPS 2013. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems that the problem was with GNAT 2012, I updated to GNAT 2013 and autocomplete works perfectly. Thanks Simon Wright for the hint.